# Outlook VBA - can view email Source Code?

Tags: vba, outlook

In MS Outlook, I want to loop through each selected email, and for each email, view the source code and check if the source file (as in txt format) contains a certain string "XX". Since using view source code can display the email content into html format and I would like to trace some format which with issues in the text.

Currently, I am doing manually by opening the mail, right click > View source > Ctrl+F to find the string I am looking for.

Is there a view to use VBA to do the action of "view source" in the email?

```
Dim individualItem As Object
For Each individualItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    'View Source Code of the email

    'Find "XX" in the email body content
     If Instr(individualItem.body, "XX") = 1 Then
     Msgbox ("Find string!")
     End if

Next Message
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the source that is not on the email body?

Answer (score 1):

By "source" do you mean the MIME headers of the message? They are stored in the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property - take a look at the message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button). You can reads that property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The DASL name of the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F"`.

Note that full MIME source of a message is never stored by Outlook - MIME is not native Outlook format.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, I see two issues:
1.) There are two distinct properties `Body` (only text) and `HTMLBody`.
2.) `Instr` returns the position of the search token. It can be any positive number if the token is found.

So try:

```
If Instr(individualItem.HTMLBody, "XX") <> 0 Then
```

Comment: Thans Keku. Do you know any vba code can "view source" of the email content - that's my question. After view source, it will display in txt with html code of the email. I want to get to that part before I do the Instr search

Comment: I didn't see that's part of your question, but I don't know if you can trigger this from code. You have the text however right there in `HTMLBody`. Outlook seems to just save this to a temporary text file and open it, you can do just the same with few lines of code.